# checkbox size varied in IE7

Tags: html, css, checkbox, internet-explorer-7

I have input checkbox in login page.this checkbox is working fine in mozilla.but in IE it is not displaying properly, checkbox size showing in IE is big as compare to mozilla.so alignment changed littel bit as compare to mozilla and IE.how to resolve it.
My code is

```
  <input type="checkbox" id="ChkRemember" runat="server" style="width: 18px; margin: 5px 15px 15px 5px; top: 153px; left: 706px; position: absolute;" />
```

Comment: This has what to do with C#? Removed tag.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but have you checked that you're not zoomed in past 100% in Internet Explorer?

Comment: thanks for your reply.but can't understand.IE only differ from all browsers

Comment: Internet Explorer (and other browsers) have a ZOOM feature.  I think you may have zoomed IE past 100%.  This makes everything larger.  You can do this by pressing the control key and then scrolling with your mouse.  Based on your code and explanation, I don't think this is an HTML, CSS, Checkbox issue.  I think you've zoomed. :-)